Android and PC use adb for communication, sleep needs to be added to execute normally
I am trying to use a data cable to allow my tablet and PC to communicate normally. I am currently using the adb mapping port method and then using socket for communication. If I do not add sleep when sending, my PC cannot receive messages normally. If I add sleep, my PC can receive messages normally. This is strange, no matter what I add, it is not as effective as a sleep
I tried adding the close and flush methods to the socket, but they had no effect
this is my code
clinet:
` static  int loaclPort = 10025;
    static  int servicePort = 10025;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> devices = getConnectedDevices();
            if (devices.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("没有连接设备");
            } else {
                boolean checkport = isPortUsed("127.0.0.1",loaclPort);
                if(!checkport){
                    try {
                        // 执行adb forward命令
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb forward tcp:" + loaclPort + " tcp:" + servicePort);
                        process.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("端口转发成功！");
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("端口转发失败！");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("连接的设备有："+checkport);
                for (String device : devices) {
                    System.out.println(device);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static List<String> getConnectedDevices() throws IOException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb devices");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        List<String> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("device")) {
                devices.add(line.split("\t")[0]);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return devices;
    }
    public static boolean isPortUsed(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
            socket.setSoLinger(true, 100);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"123\",\"id\":123456}";
            byte[] data = jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8");
            os.write(data);
            os.write(data);
            os.write(data);
            os.write(data);
            os.write(data);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String serverMessage = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("服务器回复：" + serverMessage);
            os.flush();
            socket.close();
            return true; // 端口被占用
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
            // return false; // 端口未被占用
        }
    }
}`


service:
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10025);
                    while(true) {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.e("hehe", "run: " + inputLine+clientSocket.getPort());
                            System.out.println("Received: " + inputLine);
                        }
//                        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
//                        String serverMessage = "Hello from server!";
//                        byte[] data = serverMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
//                        os.write(data);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
                        clientSocket.close();
}


AFAIR sockets are always buffered. Thus if you want to make sure data is really sent (and does not just stay in the outgoing buffer) perform a flush() after writing it to the OutputStream.

How can I confirm if the writing is complete?

As I wrote, execute flush() n the stream after writing to it. That enforces the stream to send the buffered data.

Yes, I added it, but I still need to add sleep, otherwise I won't be able to complete the data transfer properly. Do I need to add any additional judgments?

I think your main problem is the client code. You call socket.getInputStream() after writing the data. Which means that if the server is faster than the client the connection had already been closed before the client had started to read. For bidirectional communication always open input and output stream directly at the beginning.
